# How to allow for half SupportMapFragment and half linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments

I have added a Google maps fragment to an an xml layout but it takes up the full screen.Does anyone know if its possible to allow for the layout dimensions of the fragment to take u half of the screen and the other half a linear or even relative layout? I came up with this mock up to illustrate my meaning.My layout code is also posted below.Can someone offer me some pointers on this issue?

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LinearLayout with weights.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the destination entered in the textbox below fragment and the fragment will show the route from current location to input destination? Or is this not aloud using the Google maps api v3? I'm curious as I read somewhere that its not aloud to use it for driving directions..

Comment: @BrianJ no idea about that. its api v2 actually

Comment: Oh okay,I think v2 is deprecated?

Comment: @BrianJ no https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: @BrianJ its possible with map apiv2 top show route from current location to destination

Comment: Yes I will be using v2 as I think v3 is too slow from what I have read.

Comment: @BrianJ you are confused i guess https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/. for android its maps apiv2 unless you want to use java script

Comment: yes I understand I will be using api v2 now because I have searched and it says that the v3 version is not for Android as you said.thanks